# Entidade associativa Entity Framework update e delete

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, entity-framework

Tenho uma tabela aluno que tem relacionamento muitos para muitos com a tabela curso.
Assim resultando na tabela `CursoAluno`.

Gostaria de saber a maneira correta para o `update` e o `delete` da tabela `CursoAluno`.

Por exemplo quando houver uma atualização relacionada ao relacionamento `AlunoXCurso`, preciso deletar todos os dados relacionados aquele Aluno e adicionar tudo de novo ou tem uma maneira mais correta?

Comment: Quando você trocar o aluno de curso, você literalmente somente mexeria na tabela `CursoAluno`. Imagino que nesta tabela deve ter o ID do aluno, id do curso e outros dados. Você somente mexe nela.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Essa questão, em antemão, é *conceitual* e não tem relação ao Entity Framework em si.

Sobre a sua dúvida, você deve pensar como `Aluno` e `Curso`: cursos existem sem alunos e alunos existem sem cursos; um aluno pertence a um curso, mas um curso pertence a sua empresa.

Em suma, a **melhor** prática, no *meu* ponto de vista, é criar uma tabela de interploração, basicamente como a `CursoAluno` que você fez, só que mais bem lapidada.

Vamos pensar:

- Um aluno pode ***estar*** em mais de um curso?

  - Se sim, então a nomenclatura está errada: `CursosAluno` seria o melhor caso, afinal, um aluno pode pertencer à mais de um curso simultaneamente.

    - Tabelas que interploram devem ter sua estrutura trivial e simples – isso as tornam flexíveis. Abaixo, um exemplo que eu gosto e pratico muito, mas que vão *provavelmente* te exigir chaves estrangeiras de dependência para *ambas* as colunas, porque se um ou outro – aluno ou curso – deixar de existir, o relacionamento – a princípo – deve ser desfeito. *Lembrando que, com essa estrutura, as demais tabelas estão livres para serem modificadas porque não afetam diretamente as suas culturas, somente como elas interagem entre si.*

> **CursosAluno.sql**
>
> ```
> +----+----------+----------+
> | id | aluno_id | curso_id |
> +----+----------+----------+
> | 1  | 1        | 1        |
> +----+----------+----------+
> | 2  | 1        | 2        |
> +----+----------+----------+
> ```

- - Se não, então você **não precisa** dessa tabela de interploração que é a atual `CursoAluno`. A única coisa necessária seria que você colocasse na tabela `Alunos` um campo chamado `curso_id` – então, estarás apto a trabalhar com a flexibilidade desejada.

Dando profundidade ao seu caso, vamos considerar o seguinte:

> **Cursos.sql**
>
> ```
> +----+----------------+
> | id | name           |
> +----+----------------+
> | 1  | C#             |
> +----+----------------+
> | 2  | PHP            |
> +----+----------------+
> | 3  | Banco de dados |
> +----+----------------+
> ```
>
> **Alunos.sql**
>
> ```
> +----+----------------+
> | id | name           |
> +----+----------------+
> | 1  | João           |
> +----+----------------+
> ```

Então, vamos considerar que **João** esteja marticulado em **C#** e **Banco de dados**. A sua tabela `CursosAluno` ficará assim:

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id | aluno_id | curso_id |
+----+----------+----------+
| 1  | 1        | 1        |
+----+----------+----------+
| 2  | 1        | 3        |
+----+----------+----------+
```

Agora, você quer realocá-lo de `C#` para `PHP`, então nós *removemos* a linha `WHERE aluno_id = 1 AND curso_id = 1` e então adicionamos um novo registro para  `aluno_id = 1` e `curso_id = 2`.

Desse jeito, teremos o seguinte resultado:

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id | aluno_id | curso_id |
+----+----------+----------+
| 1  | 1        | 2        |
+----+----------+----------+
| 2  | 1        | 3        |
+----+----------+----------+
```

Se você parar pra pensar, nós temos uma estrutura unânime e independente, de fácil manutenção e com conceito simples.

Comment: Certo. Agora vamos supor que o Aluno está matriculado no curso de **C#** e **banco de dados**. Então ele se desmatricula do curso de **C#** e matricula-se no curso de **PHP**. Como eu trato isso na tabela CursosAluno?

Comment: Respondi com uma edição, @DiegoZanardo.

Comment: Mas @GuilhermeOberdenge, pensando em um sistema dinâmico, onde esses cursos estão dispostos em uma lista de checkbox. Como eu faria para saber se vai ser um INSERT ou um UPDATE? O mais "fácil" não seria eu deletar os registros da tabela CursosAluno relacionados ao Aluno X e inserir novamente de acordo com a lista de checkbox?

Comment: Não existe `update` nesse processo. Você vai adicionar e remover o que for necessário e ponto. Se o usuário saiu do `C#`, então você remove essa relação da tabela `CursosAluno`; se o usuário entrou em `PHP`, então você adiciona. Na edição do meu post, aliás, eu tinha deixado isso explítico: remoção e adição - não há alteração.

Answer (score 10):

***Diagrama das tabelas e seus relacionamentos (N - M)***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Entidades e DbContext***

```
//Representa Tabela Aluno
[Table("Aluno")]
public class Aluno
{
    public Aluno()
    {
        this.Cursos = new HashSet<Curso>();
    }
    [Key()]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AlunoId { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Curso> Cursos { get; set; }
}
//Representa Tabela Curso
[Table("Curso")]
public  class Curso {
    public Curso ()
    {
        this.Alunos = new HashSet<Aluno>();
    }

    [Key()]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CursoId { get; set; }
    public String Descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Aluno> Alunos { get; set; }
}
//Representa o DbContext
public class Context: DbContext
{
    public Context()
        : base("Data Source=.\\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=BaseDados;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=senha") { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {       
        modelBuilder.Entity<Curso>()
                .HasMany(a => a.Alunos)
                .WithMany(c => c.Cursos)
                .Map(x =>
                {
                    x.MapLeftKey("CursoId");
                    x.MapRightKey("AlunoId");
                    x.ToTable("CursoAluno");
                });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    public DbSet<Curso> Curso { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Aluno> Aluno { get; set; }
}
```

***Operações***

### Inserir

*Nesse procedimento foi inserido Curso na tabela Curso, Aluno na Tabela Aluno. Após isso foi inserido o Curso dentro dos Cursos de Aluno (na tabela de relacionamento N - M).*

```
Context db = new Context();

//INSERINDO CURSO NA TABELA CURSO
Curso curso = new Curso();
curso.Descricao = "Informática Basica";

//INSERINDO ALUNO NA TABELA ALUNO
Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
aluno.Nome = "Aluno Nome 1";

//ADICIONANDO NO CONTEXTO
db.Curso.Add(curso);
db.Aluno.Add(aluno);

//INSERINDO CURSO PARA O ALUNO
aluno.Cursos.Add(curso);

//SALVANDO REALMENTE OS DADOS
db.SaveChanges();
```

### Excluir

*Essa exclusão tem referência com a tabela CursoAluno aonde o Curso que está dentro de Alunos será excluido. Esse Curso na tabela Curso existirá normalmente, ou seja, foi excluido da tabela de relacionamento e não da tabela principal de Curso*

```
Context db = new Context();
//EXCLUIR DO ALUNO 1 O CURSO 1
Aluno aluno = db.Aluno.Find(1);
Curso curso = aluno.Cursos.Where(x => x.CursoId == 1).FirstOrDefault();
if (curso != null)
{
    aluno.Cursos.Remove(curso);
}
//SALVANDO REALMENTE OS DADOS
db.SaveChanges();
```

*Quando se trabalha com relacionamento N-M fazemos as duas operações de Adicionar e Remover, as atualizações são feitas diretamente em Aluno e Curso visto que as mesmas possui todos os campos necessários para tal.*

### Update

```
Context db = new Context();
Aluno aluno = db.Aluno.Find(1);
aluno.Nome = "Alterando o nome";

Curso curso = db.Curso.Find(1);
curso.Descricao = "Alterando Curso";

db.SaveChanges();
```

*Obs: Nesse trecho pode se fazer a atualização dos dados principais de Aluno e Cursos e trabalhar também com Delete e Add na tabela de relacionamento.*

***Exemplo***

```
Context db = new Context();
Aluno aluno = db.Aluno.Find(1);
aluno.Nome = "Alterando o nome";

//Novo curso que vai ser adicionado na tabela de Curso e relacionamento para o Aluno existente
Curso curso = new Curso();
curso.Descricao = "C#";

aluno.Cursos.Add(curso);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: @Diego Zanardo eu acho essa resposta melhor.