# O que é Tabela Associativa?

Tags: c#, sql, banco-de-dados, entity-framework, modelagem

Bem, vejo alguns exemplos de códigos utilizando tabelas associativas. Porém não sei ao certo o que significa este termo, sua aplicabilidade, o conceito etc...

**O que é uma tabela associativa?**

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14880/entidade-associativa-entity-framework-update-e-delete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tabela, ou entidade associativa (depende de como o modelo está sendo definido), também chamada de tabela de ligação ou amarração ou ainda agregação, é uma tabela usada para intermediar duas tabelas que se relacionam em ambos os sentidos, geralmente em N : N, mas ao contrário da crença popular. ela pode ser usada para lidar com tabelas de outras [cardinalidades](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146425/101).

Pense nela como uma tabela extra com uma lista de referências através de chave estrangeira. Mas ela ocorre dos dois lados ligando duas tabelas em vez de apenas uma.

É muito comum que essas tabelas possuam apenas colunas com referências para uma tabela e a outra, além do identificador de chave primária (ele pode ser evitado usando uma chave composta pelos identificadores das duas tabelas). Mas algumas podem ter alguma informação adicional, eventualmente descrevendo até mesmo indiretamente a motivação da relação.

É possível resolver de outras formas, mas frequentemente terão outros problemas, por exemplo um uso excessivo de colunas com valor nulo e/ou espaço desperdiçado junto com limitação de quanto o N vale.

Ela dá mais flexibilidade, mas complica um pouco por exigir um `JOIN` extra em grande parte das situações.

[Imagem da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) demonstrando como o mapeamento funciona:

[image: Diagrama com a relação entre filmes e atores]

Desta forma você consegue achar os filmes que um ator fez e os atores que estão presentes em um filme. Sem esta tabela teria que usar duas tabelas para listar, o que complicaria muito várias operações, tornando tudo ineficiente, ou colocar a lista do que cada um participa na própria tabela das entidades principais.

Justamente porque é o padrão e tende ser mais fácil fazer tudo sem uma tabela auxiliar muitas pessoas preferem usar NoSQL. O que é um erro, porque é possível fazer o mesmo com SQL, elas só não aprenderam como faz, elas só seguem as receitas de bolo mais comuns que usam tabelas associativas. Mas também é um erro porque isso tem lá sua ineficiência, criando problemas futuros se não tomar muito cuidado para manter os dados sincronizados.

Um exemplo de tabelas também da Wikipedia (se você acha isso difícil, provavelmente programação não é para você):

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    UserLogin varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    UserPassword varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    UserName varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Permissions (
    PermissionKey varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    PermissionDescription varchar(500) NOT NULL
);

-- Tabela associativa.
CREATE TABLE UserPermissions (
    UserLogin varchar(50) REFERENCES Users (UserLogin),
    PermissionKey varchar(50) REFERENCES Permissions (PermissionKey),
    PRIMARY KEY (UserLogin, PermissionKey)
);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Dei exemplos em outras respostas como [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/430721/101) e [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326221/101).

Answer (score 4):

A cardinalidade N para N leva para o modelo lógico a necessidade de definição de mais um entidade. Chamamos isto de ASSOCIATIVA.

Ou seja isso ocorre em casos onde voce pretende realizar um relacionamento N para N.

De uma olhada http://www.macoratti.net/cbmd1.htm