# Criação de tabelas com cardinalidade 1 : N

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cardinalidade

Tenho duas tabelas, `PRODUTOS` e `INSUMOS`. Para criar um produto preciso de vários insumos, gostaria de saber como devo proceder com essa relação no MySQL.
Devo criar uma tabela chamada `COMPOSICAO` e nela trabalhar somente com chave estrangeira, essa seria uma forma, existem outras?

Como devo proceder com esse tipo de ralação no Laravel?

Comment: Isso vai depender do contexto ou do escopo. Para você o que seria esta `COMPOSICAO`? Aproveite e faça um [tour] também.

Comment: vou dar um exemplo de como imagino `COMPOSICAO`, digamos que vc vai fabricar um carro, quais os itens que compõe o carro, motor, caixa de marcha, parabrisa etc.

Comment: Dá uma pesquisada sobre formas normais, no seu caso se aplica a 3a forma normal.http://aprendaplsql.com/modelagem-de-dados/normalizacao-banco-de-dados/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente precisa de uma tabela auxiliar de associação ou amarração ou intersecção de produtos com insumos (isto é chamado entidade associativa), onde fará a ligação entre eles. Imagino que seja essa composição que está falando, mas não tenho certeza por não ter detalhes.

[image: DER com entidade associativa]

Em essência terá o código do produto e o código do insumo em cada linha e que já será a chave primária. É comum ter uma chave secundária com o inverso insumo-produto. Não sei se é isso que quer dizer com chave estrangeira.

Especificamente no Laravel não sei o que fazer, mas imagino que deva ter que criar uma tabela assim no modelo dele. Eu sei que alguns tenderão a querer fazer um grafo de objetos em memória. Pra mim isso é um erro, reproduza o modelo do banco de dados e seja mais feliz.

Comment: Caso eu faça como citei acima não estarei fazendo errado??

Comment: Imagino que está tudo ok, se fizer como eu falei.

Answer (score -1):

Se um insumo não se repetir em mais de um produto, você pode colocar uma chave estrangeira na tabela Insumos,

```
Insumos (*id*, nome, idproduto)
Produto (*id*, nome)
```

Assim, você garante que nenhum outro produto terá aquele insumo.

Caso contrário, você está correto. Deve-se ter uma tabela auxiliar do tipo Composição,

```
Composição (*idproduto, idinsumo*)
```