# Como armazenar lista de produtos de um pedido em tabela do banco de dados?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, chave-estrangeira

Eu tenho a seguinte modelagem do banco de dados até então:

[image: Modelo]

Estou com dúvida de qual a melhor forma de armazenar os produtos na tabela de pedidos.

Uma *string* com `Id` de todos os produtos para cada pedido na tabela? Acho muito ruim. Qual outra solução seria melhor?

Depois quero conseguir buscar um pedido e seus produtos relacionados a ele.

Comment: Como a relação entre pedido e produto é de `N - N` (um produto pode estar em vários pedidos, assim como um pedido pode ter vários produtos), você pode criar uma **tabela associativa**, onde cada registro contenha o **id do produto** e o **id do pedido**, permitindo que você realize consultas como "todos os produtos para X pedido" ou "todos os pedidos que tenham X produto".

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando estamos trabalhando com um banco relacional nós buscamos estabelecer uma **relação** entre as tabelas quando fazer sentido. Como é o seu caso.

No seu caso, você precisa estabelecer uma relação entre pedidos (*orders*) e produtos (*products*).

Um pedido é feito de vários produtos e isto faz todo sentido. Então seu raciocínio está correto, porém a forma de executá-lo não.

Partindo do seu problema, podemos estabelecer algumas coisas para chegar em uma sugestão de solução final:

- Um pedido tem vários produtos
- Os produtos podem pertencer a mais de um pedido

Para estabelecer este relacionamento entre pedido e produto, ele pode ocorrer usando as propriedades já existentes dos bancos relacionais. Para isto, temos o que chamamos de "chave estrangeira". Uma chave estrangeira faz uma ligação de uma tabela com outra, guardando o identificador único (chave) da outra tabela.

Na maioria dos casos, podemos estabelecer a relação entre 2 tabelas colocando a chave estrangeira em uma delas. A escolha dependerá do relacionamento. Por exemplo, se uma pessoa pode ter mais de um endereço, e o endereço só pertence a pessoa, podemos colocar uma chave estrangeira no endereço com a chave da pessoa. Algo assim:

```
pessoa
id  | nome   
100 | Dherik
102 | Luan

endereco
id  | rua            | pessoa_id
400 | Rua Chile      | 100
401 | Rua Argentina  | 102
402 | Rua Peru       | 100
```

Contudo, no seu caso, não parece fazer sentido o produto ter a chave de pedido em sua tabela, pois o produto pode pertencer a mais de um pedido e um pedido pode estar associado com vários produtos.

Para resolver isto, você pode criar uma tabela intermediária para associar pedido e produto: a tabela `pedido_produto`. Assim, você teria este resultado (vou omitir algumas colunas por simplificação):

```
produto
id | name
5  | Garrafa
6  | Mouse
7  | Teclado

pedido
id | idClient
2  | 33
9  | 236

pedido_produto
id_pedido | id_produto
2         | 5
9         | 7
9         | 5
9         | 6
```

Desta forma, a tabela `pedido_produto` consegue estabelecer quais pedidos são associados a quais produtos.

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa de uma tabela de itens de pedido. Isto é chamado **entidade associativa**. Esta tabela estaria ligada ao pedido e uma entrada nela só existe porque existe um pedido. Isto é [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101) básica.

Nesta tabela você teria uma chave primária composta pelo número do pedido mais o sequencial do item entrado. Poderia só colocar o código do produto, mas em uma aplicação real nunca é tão simples (por isso que eu falo que exemplos artificiais nunca ensinam bem como fazer algo, fazer um carro de papel é muito diferente de fazer um carro para andar nas ruas). Em geral terão vários dados referentes a este item do pedido.

Nem todos casos você precisa pesquisar os itens individualmente, por isso pode não ser tão vantajoso.

Por outro lado se for só o código mesmo, então não vejo algo tão ruim assim de fazer uma lista de `ids` na própria tabela. Não é tão comum fazerem isso no modelo relacional, mas não acho tão ruim quando faz sentido. Para um exemplo artificial que provavelmente é um exercício eu faria o relacionamento porque o objetivo deve ser este. Em caso real nem seria adequado como falei nos parágrafos anteriores, mas se fosse, tem alguns casos que pode ser melhor.

O modelo relacional foi criado em uma época que se exigia pureza, e os mecanismos existentes eram limitados para lidar com dados variáveis. Você precisa pensar na necessidade e na pureza do modelo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).